# Trying to pass the output of echo into mkdir command

Tags: terminal, echo, pipeline, mkdir

I know that `echo` command prints all it's arguments and it does not reads from stdin.

But when I am trying to make `echo NAME | mkdir` it tells me: `mkdir: missing operand`.

I tried to read from `man mkdir`, but it does not tells me where mkdir reads from.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're passing the name as input, mkdir expects an argument

Try:

```
echo NAME | xargs mkdir
```

xargs here provides exactly the missing link: it takes the input stream, and passes it to the program (mkdir, in this case) as *arguments*.
Note that this parses whitespace-separated elements as different args, so use this with care.

For more information just look at `man xargs`

Comment: Oh cool, it's working.
Could you explain me why and what is xargs?

Comment: @FineasSilaghi, edited my answer. I think xargs is one of the most useful utility-that-most-people-never-heard-of in linux